# TextView does not show its value assigned to it

Tags: android, xml

Can any one tells me why the value of the `TextView` is not showing. I assign value to the `TextView` programmaticall but it is not showing. I also try to assign value to that `TextView` using `android:Text` but the Text never appears. Any Idea why that happens. Please see the xml file below.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogContainer">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogRelativeLayout00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogTableLayout00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogTableRow00"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogTitleMessageValue"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="zsfsafsFS DSFAS"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogTableRow01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogMessageValue"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogTableRow02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogBtnYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogBtnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

JavaCode:

```
    emptyDBWarningDialog.setCancelable(true);
    LayoutInflater mDialogInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    View DialogInflatedView = mDialogInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_saved_locations_emptydatabasewarningdialog, null);
    emptyDBWarningDialog.setContentView(DialogInflatedView);

    emptyDBWarningDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);

    LinearLayout mLL = (LinearLayout) emptyDBWarningDialog.findViewById(R.id.mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogContainer);
    TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) emptyDBWarningDialog.findViewById(R.id.emptyDataBaseWarningDialogTitleMessageValue);
    TextView dialogMsg = (TextView) emptyDBWarningDialog.findViewById(R.id.emptyDataBaseWarningDialogMessageValue);
    Button yesBtn = (Button) emptyDBWarningDialog.findViewById(R.id.emptyDataBaseWarningDialogBtnYes);
    Button cancelBtn = (Button) emptyDBWarningDialog.findViewById(R.id.emptyDataBaseWarningDialogBtnCancel);

    dialogTitle.setText(EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_TITLE);
    dialogMsg.setText(EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_MSG);

    emptyDBWarningDialog.show();
```

Comment: which color of your background `@drawable/dialog_border` ?

Comment: Just for curiosity... why do you use such **long and unpractical ids**? i.e.: `android:id="@+id/mySavedLocationsEmptyDataBaseWarningDialogRelativeLayout00"`. And... do you **really need** to have everything with an id assigned?

Comment: @DerGolem i just tring to avoid duplicate ids

Comment: It's **not necessary** to give an id to everything (do you use all of them in your Java code or refer them all in your layout?). If you really have to, you can number things like "fantasy_0000", ..., "fantasy_9999". Shorter.

Comment: @DerGolem I appreciate your advice and i think i will consider it from now on

Comment: post your whole layout code

Comment: You said you set the value to the `TextView` programmatically. I'm positive that will be where you find the mistake. Can you paste the Activity.class code please?

Comment: @JRadtheBad yes i set the value programmatically, and when i found that there is no value appears, i chose to set value through `android:text` but after all still nothing appears

Comment: @JRadtheBad please see the java code posted above

Comment: Well, you set the text for both of those `TextView`s to whatever value your `public static` variables of `EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_TITLE` and `EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_MSG` are set to. Those values will ALWAYS override anything you put inside the XML because they happen after the XML is used to generate the layout. Where did you set the values for those two static variables?

Comment: @JRadtheBad `EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_TITLE` and `EMPTY_DATABASE_DIALOG_MSG` are global variable assigned to some text values"string". is that what are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout really depends on your design.
In this case, a single RelativeLayout which has it's children set in relation to itself and/or to one another is preferrable.

One single RelativeLayout also keeps down the View count, for better performances.

A TextView can hold up to 4 compound drawables (and also a background).
These can be set near the top, bottom, left and/or right side.
In your case, android:drawableLeft would make the perfect icon for your TextView

---

Now this is my **extreme makeover** to your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmptyDB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="zsfsafsFS DSFAS"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Yes"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Cancel"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Maybe, you'd like to tweak the two bottom Buttons in a LinearLayout, just to set their weights to 1 and widths to 0dp (in order to make them fill the bottom line 50% and 50%)

Like this (only the last part is shown, since the rest is the same):

```
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnYes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Yes"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just suspected the `TableLayout` and changed it to `RelativeLayout`, so that the final xml_File looks like the layout below. And values of the `textview` appears normally. But I still DO NOT know whhat is the problem with the `TableLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/myContainer">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/WarningDialogIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WarningDialogTitleMsgVal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emptyDataBaseWarningDialogIcon"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WarningDialogMsgVal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_border">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BtnYes"
        android:text="Cancel"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: **T** he outer LinearLayout can be deleted and all you need is a single RelativeLayout. **Y** ou still have kilometric ids. **f** ill_parent is deprecated as of API level 8 (use match_parent). **T** extViews can include pictures (as compound drawables), to save a View and enhance performances.

Comment: @DerGolem I really liked "kilometric ids" expression, i think i will modify that later. your last piece of advice regarding the "TextViews" i did not get it, do you mean that i can dispense with the `imageView` or what do you mean? sorry for misunderstanding. One more thing please, if I can delete the `LinearLayout`, so when should utilize it OR when it is useful. Sorry if am asking too much

Comment: Wether to use a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout really depends on your design. In this case, a single RelativeLayout which has it's children set in **relation** to itself and/or to one another is preferrable. One sigle RelativeLayout also keeps down the View count, for better performances. A TextView can hold up to 4 compound drawables (and also a background). These can be set near the top, bottom, left and/or right side. In your case, `android:drawableLeft` would make the perfect icon for your TextView.